# How do you make Ace Editor Grow and fill a table cell in the same fashion a div does?

Tags: javascript, html, css, markdown

How do you make Ace Editor Grow and fill a table cell in the same fashion a div does? I just want `manuscript` editor div to Grow and fill in the same manner as the `Article` div makes the whole page grow in height.

Code is @https://github.com/viruliant/gh-template/
Demo is @https://viruliant.github.io/gh-template/

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><!--_________________--><title>
viruliant.github.io/gh-template
</title><meta name="description" content="Github Pages Template using client-side JS markdown for styling  plaintext .md files">
<!--___________________________________________________________________Styles-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/jquery-ui.theme.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./default.css"/>
<style type="text/css">/* <![CDATA[ Custom Styling*/
#Page-Table { min-height:100%; width:100%; margin:0; }
#Page-Table, #Content, #Left, #Right, #Header, #Footer, #Manuscript, #Manuscript { height:100%;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; position: relative;
    border:0; margin:0; padding:0;
}
#Page-Table, #Left-cell, #Right-cell, #Content-cell, #Header-cell, #Footer-cell {
    border:0; padding:0; border-collapse: collapse;
}
#Left-cell, #Right-cell { width:10%; }
#Content-cell { height: 100%; width:80%; }
#Header-cell, #Footer-cell { height:64px; }

#Header, #Footer { background: #FFF; }
/* ]]> */</style>
<!--__________________________________________________________________Scripts-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script>
<script src="./ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/ace.js"></script>
<script src="./showdown/compressed/Showdown.min.js"></script>
<script src="./showdown/compressed/extensions/table.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="requirejs/require.js"></script>-->
<script src="./default.js"></script><script>/* <![CDATA[ Custom JS*/window.onload = function() {
    $( "#Content" ).tabs({ event: "mouseover" });// http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

    //Setup Manuscript Editor
    var Editor = ace.edit("Manuscript");
    Editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
    Editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/markdown");
    //set contents of Manuscript to "index.md" file contents
    jQuery.get('README.md', function(data) { Editor.setValue(data); });

    //startup showdownjs to reset Article contents on Manuscript changes
    var converter = new Showdown.converter({ extensions: ['table'] });
    Editor.getSession().on('change', function(e) {
        document.getElementById("Article").innerHTML = converter.makeHtml(Editor.getValue())
        //MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"Article"])
        //$("#Article").children().addClass("ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom");
    });
//  Editor.resize();
};/* ]]> */</script>
<!--____________________________________________________________--></head><body>
<table id="Page-Table"><!--https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAZTr.jpg-->
    <tr><td id="Header-cell" colspan="3"><div id="Header"></div></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="Left-cell"><div id="Left"></div></td>
        <td id="Content-cell">
            <div id="Content">
                <ul><li><a href="#Article">Article</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Manuscript">Manuscript</a></li></ul>
                <div id="Article"></div>
                <div id="Manuscript"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="Right-cell"><div id="Right"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td id="Footer-cell" colspan="3"><div id="Footer"></div></td></tr>
</table>
<!--___________________________________________________________--></body></html>
```

UPDATE: To test your changes you can just do a `git clone --recursive https://github.com/viruliant/gh-template/` and open the index.html OR run the nodejs file to get the [readme.md](https://github.com/viruliant/gh-template/blob/98ac494c5a6a2b43e6797671fbcacca370faf1e5/index.html#L39) line to work properly

Comment: First thing is that your demo page breaks in firefox#35.0:
   You will have to give the following for it to not break:
   
    `#Content-cell {
    height: 100%; <------
    width: 80%;
    }`

Comment: Did you mean this question is fixed, or the firefox issue which I pointed out? If the question is fixed, then can you also post a quick answer so others wont waste time on this question.. and also get to learn something new when they read the answer?

Comment: @Aditya Patch applied, firefox issue fixed

Comment: Can you give everyone a quick explanation on what your patch included to fix your problem?

Comment: @aditya before your patch you couldn't see anything at all in firefox, now it is identical to chrome behavior.

Comment: Oh right. So your actual problem still persists... I thought you applied a path to fix that. Geez.

Comment: @Aditya Usually I don't test firefox til chrome is working right, I should have just posted this: https://github.com/MinJSLib/gh-template/commit/98ac494c5a6a2b43e6797671fbcacca370faf1e5

Comment: It's generally best to have a testable sample within SO so that any future viewers looking for the same fix can find all the information here, rather than going to external sources that may change over time or disappear altogether.

Comment: @Klors if you're on a windows machine and do not have access to git clone --recursive command you can simply fork the project then click edit file & see any changes you submit at https://YourUserNameHere.github.io/gh-template/ but you may have to wait 30 mins for the 1st commit to go in.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of it working within an SO snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `div`s to behave the same, you probably just need to remove `#manuscript` from the styles where `#article` does not appear (or conversely add `#article` to the ones where `#manuscript` does).

The only one I see in your example is

```
#Page-Table, #Content, #Left, #Right, #Header, #Footer, #Manuscript, #Manuscript { height:100%;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; position: relative;
    border:0; margin:0; padding:0;
}
```

Just change it to

```
#Page-Table, #Content, #Left, #Right, #Header, #Footer { height:100%;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; position: relative;
    border:0; margin:0; padding:0;
}
```

Here's an example setting the height of the `div` and giving it a border so that you see it a little clearer within SO. You have some odd styling on your footer that overlaps the article, but that may work when you have the rest of your styles in -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Content").tabs({
    event: "mouseover"
  });

  //Setup Manuscript Editor
  var Editor = ace.edit("Manuscript");
  Editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
  Editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/markdown");
  //set contents of Manuscript to "index.md" file contents
  //jQuery.get('README.md', function(data) {
  //  Editor.setValue("Test markdown");
  //});

  //startup showdownjs to reset Article contents on Manuscript changes
  //var converter = new Showdown.converter({
  //  extensions: ['table']
  //});
var doc = Editor.getSession().getDocument();
  Editor.getSession().on('change', function(e) {
    //document.getElementById("Article").innerHTML = converter.makeHtml(Editor.getValue())
      //MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"Article"])
      //$("#Article").children().addClass("ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom");
      // using current line-height of 14 pixels...
      $("#Manuscript").css({"height": (14 * doc.getLength()) + 'px'});
      Editor.resize();
  });
  //  Editor.resize();
});
```

```css
#Page-Table {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#Page-Table,
#Content,
#Left,
#Right,
#Header,
#Footer {
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#Page-Table,
#Left-cell,
#Right-cell,
#Content-cell,
#Header-cell,
#Footer-cell {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#Left-cell,
#Right-cell {
  width: 10%;
}
#Content-cell {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
}
#Header-cell,
#Footer-cell {
  height: 64px;
}
#Header,
#Footer {
  background: #FFF;
}
#Article,
#Manuscript {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.3/ace.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/0.3.1/showdown.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="Page-Table">
    <tr>
      <td id="Header-cell" colspan="3">
        <div id="Header"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="Left-cell">
        <div id="Left"></div>
      </td>
      <td id="Content-cell">
        <div id="Content">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#Article">Article</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#Manuscript">Manuscript</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div id="Article"></div>
          <div id="Manuscript"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td id="Right-cell">
        <div id="Right"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="Footer-cell" colspan="3">
        <div id="Footer"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not working, but semi-promising result. added a section to the question on how to test changes.

Comment: The page isn't growing in height in your answer.

Comment: What page isn't growing in height?

Comment: You got it to fill the cell properly, but it doesn't make the whole page grow just like the article div does in the demo page.

Comment: I see, well, you can remove the height CSS and set it via some javascript after the editor is used. You may also want to uncomment out the resize call that you had at the end.

Comment: @GlassGhost Also, the showdown url in my example isn't an issue, that's how you specify that it should be loaded using the protocol that the page as a whole is using. Although, I have left out the reference to the table extension that you have.

Comment: Accepted answer, https://github.com/MinJSLib/gh-template/commit/531fe414a902e0674476b24488bef7c9d65dcfc7 . SO won't let me give the bounty for another 15 hours, will do when it will let me. Thank you.

Comment: The reason I'm doing this is so I can, convert my Math Cheat sheet --> http://glassghost.github.io/ to markdown. Now if only I could get mathjax working like it does on http://math.stackexchange.com/ Then maybe I can only hope to write something as beautiful as http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/ but that would be a new question.

Comment: @GlassGhost that's a nice cheat-sheet, though I fear I still wouldn't understand much that it'd be needed for even with it available. I've forgotten much of the advanced maths that I learned.

Comment: well all the Trig functions in terms of  Cos and it -1/4turn and it's reciprocals if you ever want to tell some kids how to do integration easily ;) that and a few other things is nice to have.

Comment: @GlassGhost for my own personal amusement, I also created an alternative layout/style just to see how it'd look, http://jsfiddle.net/Klors/7mb72kyk/ just in case it's of any use to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69149/discussion-between-glassghost-and-klors).